# Prevent NERDTree from switching tabs when opening a file node?

Tags: load, tabbed-user-interface, plugin-nerdtree

In NERDTree, if I select a file node and hit <kbd>o</kbd>, it opens the file in a window in the current tab. However, if that particular file is already open in another tab, NERDTree switches to that tab. I find this quite disorienting in my workflow.

Is there an option to tell NERDTree to stay in the current tab?

---

Update: I opened a pull request on the NERDTree repo at Github to add an option to prevent this tab-switching: https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/pull/417

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is currently no way to do this.

From the source code (ref. [lib/nerdtree/opener.vim line 238](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/c2dd750860288b8cf81f6bd5ff49dc5ee76a34d5/lib/nerdtree/opener.vim#L238)):

```
function! s:Opener._openFile()
    if self._reuse && self._reuseWindow()
        return
    endif
```

And the `_reuseWindow()` function (ref. [line 309](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/c2dd750860288b8cf81f6bd5ff49dc5ee76a34d5/lib/nerdtree/opener.vim#L309)):

```
function! s:Opener._reuseWindow()
    "check the current tab for the window
    let winnr = bufwinnr('^' . self._path.str() . '$')
    if winnr != -1
        call nerdtree#exec(winnr . "wincmd w")
        call self._checkToCloseTree(0)
        return 1
    else
        "check other tabs
        let tabnr = self._path.tabnr()
        if tabnr
            call self._checkToCloseTree(1)
            call nerdtree#exec('normal! ' . tabnr . 'gt')
            let winnr = bufwinnr('^' . self._path.str() . '$')
            call nerdtree#exec(winnr . "wincmd w")
            return 1
        endif
    endif
    return 0
endfunction
```

It wouldn't be too hard, however, to simply remove the entire `else`  block in the code above (or comment it out). Since we're on the Vim site, why not do it with Vim:

```
vim "+/function! s:Opener._reuseWindow()" "+/else" "+normal d9j" "+wq" lib/nerdtree/opener.vim
```

Run this command from the directory in which the NERDTree plugin is located to automagically remove this functionality.

Comment: Thanks very much. I was hoping there would be a better way or that someone had already forked NERDTree on Github to add such an option, but I'll modify my copy of NERDTree.

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is a way! It's called silent open. In NERDTree focus your cursor on the file you want to open in new tab then press <kbd>T</kbd>. this will open it silently in a new tab without switching to it.

In NERDTree press <kbd>?</kbd> to check out all the mappings available for you.

Comment: No, I actually want NERDTree to open the file in the current tab and only the current tab, without switching to an existing open buffer in a different tab.

What T does is open the file in a new tab.

Comment: Yes! Sorry I didn't get it the first time; however, this is not implemented by default in NERDTree. By default NERDTree will switch you to the file if it already exist. Which is - to most of us -  is the natural required behavior of any editor. According to my experience with NERDTree and its complement NERDTreeTabs (NERDTreeTabs makes NERDTree tab-aware, you have to install them both), you can have the same file open in multiple tab. Right now I can open a file in multiple tabs using T and t, but I have to explicitly tell NERDTree to do that.

Comment: Actually I came looking for exactly this answer, even if it doesn't answer the OP question!

Answer (score 0):

you can try  `go` , also you can add a new keymapping.

I just map `gg` key to do this,  here is my config

```
call NERDTreeAddKeyMap({
        \ 'key': 'gg',
        \ 'callback': 'NERDTreeOpenHandler',
        \ 'quickhelpText': 'open in current tab',
        \ 'scope': 'FileNode' })

func! NERDTreeOpenHandler(node)
    call a:node.open({'stay': 1, 'where': 'p', 'keepopen': 1})
endf
```

English is not my mother tongue; please excuse any errors on my part.